# js/date : How to compare a French string date like "Vendredi 22 Mai à 22h" with current Date()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare a French date in string format like `Vendredi 22 Mai à 22h` (literally `Friday 22 May at 10pm`` with the current date in javascript with node.js :

```js
const dateNow = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss'); // or maybe with new Date.now()
const dateToCompare = "Vendredi 22 Mai à 22h"

if (dateNow <= dateToCompare) {
    // Code here
}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: use `toLocaleTimeString` of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to find a way to parse the French date, browsers don't have great consistency there. Once it's been parsed, you can check which date is more recent by converting to its "primitive value"

```
const currentYear = Date.now().getFullYear(); // since this isn't in your date string.

if (Date.now() <= new Date(currentYear, 5 , 22, 22).valueOf()) {
  // code
}
```

Also see:

Date object docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Intl docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Moment docs (a popular dates library): https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I made somethink like this if it could help someone else (definitely not the best code given my JS skills) :

```
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
const monthsArr = ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin', 'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'];

const dateNow = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss');
const currentYear = dateFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy');

// Split each word
let eventDate = textDescription.split(' ');
// Organize the array to save only the necessary values : day in number, month in number and hours:minutes
eventDate = [
    eventDate[3],
    monthsArr.indexOf(eventDate[4]),
    eventDate[6]
];
// Split hours:minutes
// Modify hours number in date array
// Push minutes number to the date array
const eventHourMin = eventDate[2].split('h');
eventDate[2] = eventHourMin[0];
eventDate.push(eventHourMin[1]);
// Full date converted as yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss
const formattedEventDate = dateFormat(new Date(currentYear, eventDate[1], eventDate[0], eventDate[2], eventDate[3], '00'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss');
// If event date is not expired
if (dateNow < formattedEventDate) {
    // code here...
}
```